# add new function in controller in newsletter 404 found

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to modify on Mage module newsletter to add new action for amp requirement 
but adding new function amp showing 404 result .

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should never edit the `Mage` module directly If you do and in future, and you upgrade Magento version then you will lose your changes. To avoid this in `Magento` you can `override` the core class into your `module`. To do this you just need to create a new simple module.

So first create a `Test_Newsletter.xml` in `app/etc/modules/Test_Newsletter.xml` directory.

Now in this file you need to write below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Newsletter>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Newsletter/>
            </depends>
        </Test_Newsletter>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now you need to create a `config.xml` in `app/code/local/Test/Newsletter/etc/config.xml` this file conains configuration of your module. In this file you need to write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Newsletter>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_Newsletter>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <newsletter>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Test_Newsletter before="Mage_Newsletter">Test_Newsletter</Test_Newsletter>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </newsletter>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now create a `SubscriberController.php` in `app/code/local/Test/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php` This file `overwrites` the newsletter controller so you can add your custom method here or update existing methods. In this file, you need to write

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Newsletter').DS.'SubscriberController.php';

class Test_Newsletter_SubscriberController extends Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController
{
    public function newAction()
    {
    }
}
```

In `Test_Newsletter` `Test` is my company name `Newsletter` is module name you can update it as per your requirement. and last but not the least clear your webshop cache.